# Magento website server migration issues

Tags: php, magento

I'm currently in the process of transferring my magento instalation, alog with its database, to a new web server. I edited the config files so they would match the new domain's database data, and uploaded the same files to the other server.

When I'm trying to run the system, I get the following error:

```
Warning: include_once(Varien/Autoload.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/73/6502373/html/app/Mage.php on line 50

Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Varien/Autoload.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/content/73/6502373/html/app/code/local:/home/content/73/6502373/html/app/code/community:/home/content/73/6502373/html/app/code/core:/home/content/73/6502373/html/lib:.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php') in /home/content/73/6502373/html/app/Mage.php on line 50

Warning: include(Varien/Autoload.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/73/6502373/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 68

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Varien/Autoload.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/content/73/6502373/html/app/code/local:/home/content/73/6502373/html/app/code/community:/home/content/73/6502373/html/app/code/core:/home/content/73/6502373/html/lib:.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php') in /home/content/73/6502373/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 68

Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Autoload' not found in /home/content/73/6502373/html/app/Mage.php on line 53
```

Do you have any Idea on how I can debug this? Just put me in the right track. thanks!

Comment: Have you checked if the unfound file was actually uploaded?

Comment: Did you check direcory / file permissions?

Comment: I can't find the file. It's quite confusing actually, cause the directory structure it displays doesn't even exist in the system files. I wonder if I'm gonna have to reinstall magento from scratch...

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry to have posted such a stupid question. When I downloaded the FTP files from the original server I was dead tired and didn't realize my FTP client had failed to download the whole site. Please ignore all of this, and thanks to those who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

Moving a Magento installation may seem easy. However, there are a few gotchas. [Here](http://blog.joefallon.net/2011/03/how-to-move-a-magento-installation/) is a great procedure that I have used many times in the past.